# "StopIntegration" inside the "EventAction" is not working in the given instance

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection, eventhandler

```
ne3 := {  
          x'[t]==y[t], 
          y'[t] == +z[t], 
          z'[t] == -y[t] + 0.1 x[t]^2 + 1.1 x[t] z[t] + 1.05 
       };
ic = {-6.574827448624937`, 1.1491069082907748`, -11.346851335686967`};
xX0 = {-4.6256260771653235`, 1.049162640307589`,  0.4539787484231617`};
function = {#2, #3, 1.05 + 1/10 #1^2 - #2 + 11/10 #1 #3} &;
tangent = Echo[function[xX0[[1]], xX0[[2]], xX0[[3]]]];
equationOfPlane[point_] := Total[(point - xX0)*tangent];

countCrossings = 1; countCrossingMax = 30;
crossingPoints = RandomInteger[0, {countCrossingMax, 4}];
crossingPoints[[countCrossings]] = {0, ic[[1]], ic[[2]], ic[[3]]};
xyz = NDSolve[{ne3[[1]], ne3[[2]], ne3[[3]], x[0] == ic[[1]], 
y[0] == ic[[2]], z[0] == ic[[3]], 
WhenEvent[
 countCrossings >= countCrossingMax, {"StopIntegration"}]},
    {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 5000},
        Method -> {"EventLocator", 
 "Event" -> equationOfPlane[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}],
        Direction -> 1,
        "EventAction" :> {countCrossings = countCrossings + 1;
                    crossingPoints[[countCrossings]] = {t, x[t], y[t], z[t]};
                    tmp = Norm[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} - xX0];
                    
   If[tmp > 10^10, 
    Print["condition2 @countCrossings=" <> 
      ToString[countCrossings] <> " dist=" <> 
      ToString[TraditionalForm[tmp]]]; "StopIntegration" ];
   If[tmp < 10^-3, 
    Print["condition1 @countCrossings=" <> 
      ToString[countCrossings] <> " dist=" <> 
      ToString[TraditionalForm[tmp]]]; "StopIntegration"];}
                         }
               ];
```

The "StopIntegration" inside the WhenEvent works, but inside the last if loop inside the "EventAction" doesn't work.
If you run the code then you will get 29 times the 2nd if condition satisfied but the "StopIntegration" won't stop the integration. Finally the integration stops from the "StopIntegration" written inside WhenEvent part.

***Edit1***
Thanks to Daniel for making me notice of a typo that I just fixed.

***Edit2***
I figured out that there is not gurante that **"StopIntegration"** will work or not unless it is written inside The command **Throw[]** as
**Throw[Null,"StopIntegration"]***
Though I still haven't figured out why **"StopIntegration"** works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work if it is written outside the **Through** command.

Comment: What is "a" in function = {#2, #3, a + 1/10 #1^2 - #2 + 11/10 #1 #3} &

Comment: @DanielHuber Hey I just edited the question. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Why are you using both `WhenEvent` and `"EventLocator"`? Anyway, `"StopIntegration"` works differently in them.  In the latter, the only usage documented is `Throw[Null, "StopIntegration"]`, which returns the value `Null` to an enclosing `Catch[]` that catches the tag `"StopIntegration"`. If `"StopIntegration"` appears to work by itself, it may be because when they introduced `WhenEvent`, they mapped both onto the same event-handling routines in `NDSolve`; or maybe they've always had that fall-back. If fails to work, as an undocumented usage, it's hardly surprising.